# Creating a COM inproc server in a separate process (w/o modifying the registry)

Tags: com

I want to create a (potentially) Inproc COM object in a separate process. The regular way to do this is use COM's [DLL Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms691260.aspx) (`dllhost.exe`) but this requires changing the registry for the `CLSID` of the COM object to be created. I do not want to change the registry since I don't care if other instances of this object are created inproc I just want to create a specific object out of process.

Currently I've written a LocalServer COM object that accepts a prog-id and returns the object but it feels like re-inventing the wheel.

Is there a way to programmatically create the COM surrogate and tell it to create a COM object?

Comment: If you register inproc CLSID to be hosted by default DLL surrogate, it will still be instantiated in-process unless you explicitly deny in-process instantiation, e.g. by supplying `CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER` to `CoCreateInstance`.